# How do I programmatically create new groups with specific set of rights on XWiki?

Tags: wiki, usergroups, access-rights, xwiki

I'm writing my own XWiki Authenticator (that `extends XWikiAuthServiceImpl`) and therein, I want to create few groups, each with different sets of rights. How do I do it programmatically?

Example,

- `XWiki.MyStandardGroup` - `view`, `edit`, `comment`
- `XWiki.MyClassicGroup` - `view`, `edit`, `comment`, `script`
- `XWiki.MyAdminGroup`  - `view`, `edit`, `commit`, `script`, `delete`, `admin`

Also, I create the users programmatically. How do I give different access rights to different sets of users?

On the conceptual level, how do users (with rights) work with pages (with rights)? I tried to read the following docs:

- [Access Rights](https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/AdminGuide/Access%20Rights/)
- [Permission types](https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/AdminGuide/Access%20Rights/Permission%20types/)

They dont seem to explain these — or maybe, they do but written in a complex way without any concrete examples which makes it difficult to get the idea of how rights on different entities (pages, users and groups) work together. Here are some text from the [Access Rights](https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/AdminGuide/Access%20Rights/) which needs example to be understood:

> - **When a right has been allowed at a given level, it gets implicitly denied to anyone else at the same level**. This only applies to the right allowed. If only "View" is set to a user/group at this level, all other rights like "Edit" are still inherited. Using this implicit deny behavior is recommended over applying explicit denial.

What does the bold part even mean? I think the term *level* is used in different sense on different bullet points under the *same* **Basic rules** section.

Answer (score 3):

I feel there are three questions in this post:

1. How do I create Users and Groups programatically?
2. How does the Access Rights system work?
3. Is there an example for the text quoted from the access rights page

First an answer to the second one.

### How does the Access Rights system work - with example

There are a fixed number of rights in XWiki, like `view`, `edit`, etc.

Users can get these rights assigned directly to them, or they can be member of a group, and the group has these rights assigned to them. This assignment of rights can happen in different places (which are called "levels" in the documentation).

The "level" structure is as follows:

### Wiki levels

First there is the main wiki (that gets pre-installed when you install the wiki). Then there might be more wikis, called "sub-wikis", which you can create manually (via the "Wikis" secton from the "Burger" menu on the top right of every wiki page). This is a simple two layer hierarchy:

```
main wiki (always exists)
   |
   |--- subwiki1
   |
   |--- subwiki2
   |
   |--- subwiki3
```

Subwikis cannot be nested. I am not going into details why you might want them; oen can often go without them.
Users and groups can exist in the main wiki (which means their profile pages are located in the main wiki), or they can exist in subwikis (i.e. their profile pages are there.)
Users and Groups from the main wiki are visible in all subwikis (and can get rights assigned to them), but not the other way round - a user located in a subwiki cannot get special rights in the main wiki (and also not in another subwiki). If such users access the main wiki, they are treated as the anonymous user. They can only log in to the subwiki.

### Page levels

Second, (nearly) all data in the wiki is stored in pages. These pages are also nested, and since XWiki 7.x they can be nested arbitrarily deep. This is the other part of the "levels" structure.

For every wiki, there is a set of "top level" pages, both preinstalled and user created.
Then there are pages which are children of these "top level" pages, which in turn can have children, and so on.
As an additional complication, not all pages can have subpages. By historical convention these pages with a full name ending in `WebHome` can have children pages, others can not. This is probably transparent to the user, but important for the programmer.

There is no single "root" page to start the hierarchy. As an example, for one wiki the structure might look like:

```
Top level                Third Level
            Second Level                    Fourth Level

Main.WebHome                                             (preinstalled "Start" page)
   |       
   |------ Main.Search                                   (preinstalled search page, no subpages)
   |
   |------ Main.SomePage.WebHome                         (user created page, can have children)

Sandbox.WebHome                                          (preinstalled playground page)
   |       
   |------ Sandbox.TestPage1                             (preinstalled demo page, no subpages)
   |       
   |------ Sandbox.TestPage2                             (preinstalled demo page, no subpages)
   |       
   |------ Sandbox.TestPage3                             (preinstalled demo page, no subpages)
   |       
   |------ Sandbox.SomePage.WebHome                      (user created 2nd level page, can have children)
   
Documentation.WebHome                                    (user created top level page)
   |
   |------ Documentation.Topic1.WebHome                  (user created 2nd level page, can have children)
   |           |
   |           |------ Documentation.Topic1.SubTopic1.WebHome   (user created 3rd lvl page, can have children, too)
   |           |
   |           |------ Documentation.Topic1.SubTopic2.WebHome   (user created 3rd lvl page, can have children, too)
   |           |
   |           |------ Documentation.Topic1.SubTopic3.WebHome   (user created 3rd lvl page, can have children, too)
   |           |                  |
   |           |                  |------ Documentation.Topic1.SubTopic3.EvenMore.WebHome   (user created 4th lvl page, can have children)
   |           |
   |           .
   |           .
   |           |
   |           |------ Documentation.Topic1.SubTopicN.WebHome   (user created 3rd lvl page, can have children, too)
   |
   |------ Documentation.Topic2.WebHome                  (user created 2nd lvl page, can have children)
   .
   .
   .
   |
   |------ Documentation.TopicN.WebHome                  (user created 2nd lvl page, can have children)

....
```

### Granting rights

You now can grant a right to user or group on every page in this hierarchy by adding an Object of type `XWiki.XWikiRights` to the page itself, specifying the list of rights to grant (confusingly stored in the attribute `levels` of that object), the list of users and/or groups to grant the right to, and a `allow/deny` flag ... which we will come to later. How to do that programatically is discussed in the question: [Set user and group rights to document in XWiki](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34066573/)

In that case the right is only granted for the *page* *itself*, *not* its subpages. If you give the right `edit` on the page `Main.WebHome` to the group `XWiki.HomepageEditorsGroup`, then only members of this group can edit the page, but this does not affect subpages like `Main.Search` or `Main.SomePage.WebHome`.

That the attribute `levels` here actually stores the rights is maybe confusing - again this is another historical decision. (The software is developed since 15 years or so and the developers are commited to keep backwards compatibility). What ever the attribute is named, these are *rights*, and not the *levels* the documentation talks about.

To go on with the rights management: You can also grant a right on a *page* and *all* *its* *subpages*. This only works for pages which can have subpages. Technically this is done by adding an object of type `XWiki.XWikiGlobalRights` ... but not to the page itself, but to a subpage named `WebPreferences`. (Historical decision, again.)

So if you want to grant the `view` right to the group  `XWiki.Topic1ViewerGroup`  on the page  `Documentation.Topic1.WebHome` and its subpages like `Documentation.Topic1.SubTopic1.WebHome` or `Documentation.Topic1.SubTopic3.EvenMore.WebHome`, then you take the page `Documentation.Topic1.WebPreferences` (creating it if it does not exist), and add an object of type `XWiki.XWikiGlobalRights` to it, with the attributes:

- `level : view`
- `groups : XWiki.Topic1ViewerGroup`
- `allow: 1`

### How the rights are checked

Now the check for a specific right usually looks at a given page itself, then looks at the `WebPreferences` for that page, then at the `WebPreferences` of the parent page, and so on. (It is "going up the levels".)
The check stops as soon as it finds a "rights" object covering the right in question.

If no matching "rights" object has been found up to the top level page, then the wiki is checked. Rights on the wiki level are stored in the special page `XWiki.XWikiPreferences`, again as objects of class `XWiki.XWikiGlobalRights`.

Finally if the wiki happens to be a subwiki, the global righs on the main wiki might be consulted - again on the page names `XWiki.XWikiPreferences`, but this time in the main wiki.

#### Example 1: check for `view` right on `Documentation.Topic1.SubTopic3.WebHome`

- `Documentation.Topic1.SubTopic3.WebHome` has no `XWiki.XWikiRights` - no decision
- `Documentation.Topic1.SubTopic3.WebPreferences` has no `XWiki.XWikiGlobalRights` - no decision
- `Documentation.Topic1.WebPreferences` has an `XWiki.XWikiGlobalRights` for `view` - stop to make a decision
- Result: if the current user is in the group `XWiki.Topic1ViewerGroup`, she/he can view the page, otherwise not

#### Example 2: check for `edit` right on `Main.WebHome`

- `Main.WebHome` has a `XWiki.XWikiRights` for `edit` - stop to make a decision
- Result: only users in the `XWiki.HomepageEditorsGroup` can edit, others do not

#### Example 3: check for `edit` right on `Main.SomePage.WebHome`

- `Main.SomePage.WebHome` has no `XWiki.XWikiRights` - no decision
- `Main.SomePage.WebPreferences` has no `XWiki.XWikiGlobalRights` - no decision
- up the page hierarchy: `Main.WebPreferences` has no `XWiki.XWikiGlobalRights` - no decision either
- (that `Main.WebHome` has a `XWiki.XWikiRights` is not consulted, as the right applies only to the page itself)
- up the page hierarchy: we are already at a top-level page, so go to the wiki instead
- i.e. check `XWiki.XWikiPreferences` for a `XWiki.XWikiGlobalRights` for `edit`
- usually there is an `allow : 1`  for the `XWiki.XWikiAllGroup` which means `edit` is allowed for all users
- if there is no such settings, *and* we are in a subwiki: go up the wiki hierarchy and check the `XWiki.XWikiPreferences` of the *main* wiki
- if even there is no decision made, the `edit` right is not allowed

#### `admin` is a special case

As a simplification for the users, but complication for the concept, the `admin` right works the other way round: if the `admin` right is granted on the wiki level, it is valid on all pages. Even more, it implicitely grants all the other rights, like `view` and `edit`. (The reason for this is that users too often locked themselves out before this special rule was introduced.)

### How does the "implicit deny" work?

Now to the quote:

> - **When a right has been allowed at a given level, it gets implicitly denied to anyone else at the same level**. This only applies to the right allowed. If only "View" is set to a user/group at this level, all other rights like "Edit" are still inherited. Using this implicit deny behavior is recommended over applying explicit denial.

I try to explain by example, too:

In the **Example 1** above I wrote:

> - `Documentation.Topic1.WebPreferences` has an `XWiki.XWikiGlobalRights` for `view` - stop to make a decision
> - Result: if the current user is in the group `XWiki.Topic1ViewerGroup`, she/he can view the page, otherwise not

Here the result is either:

- allow the user to view the page (and its sub pages), if the user is member of the `XWiki.Topic1ViewerGroup`
- deny the user the right to view the page (and its sub pages), if the user is not member of the `XWiki.Topic1ViewerGroup` (i.e is "everyone else")

That is, no matter what rights the user might have otherwise - as soon as the right is set here, then only the users fulfilling the criterion in the settings are allowed to view. Everybody else is out. This is an "**implicit deny**".

As an alternative, assume someone has set a rights object on `Sandbox.WebPreferences` (i.e. affecting the "Sandbox" and all subpages):

- `level : edit`
- `groups : XWiki.Topic1ViewerGroup`
- `allow: 1`

and on`Sandbox.SomePage.WebHome` (i.e. affecting this sub page only):

- `level : edit`
- `groups : XWiki.Topic1ViewerGroup`
- `allow: 0`

The setting `allow: 0` is an "**explicit deny**": as soon as you are member of the `XWiki.Topic1ViewerGroup`, you are not allowed to edit this page. The fact that there is an `allow: 1` on a higher level in the page hierarchy (on "Sandbox" and all sub pages) does not matter, beacuse it is *not on the same level*.

### How to do that programatically?

First, the groups should be created as "terminal" sub pages (i.e. pages not having children) in the `XWiki` space, like `XWiki.MyCustomGroup`. However they seem to work wherever you want to create them.

On the other hand, users **must** be created as pages `XWiki.<LoginName>` as unfortunately there is a lot of code around that expects users to be in this location and nowhere else.

After having created the page (in the API they are called `Document`), add an object of the proper class to the page, set the attributes you want and save the page.

When looking at your requirements, it does not look like you want to grant the rights to the groups in any special place in the page hierarchy; so I assume they will be set on the wiki level. Thus no need to understand all the other explanations; just grab the `XWiki.XWikiPreferences` page and add the required `XWiki.XWikiGlobalRights` there.

I recommend using an [MandatoryDocumentInitializer](https://github.com/xwiki/xwiki-platform/blob/master/xwiki-platform-core/xwiki-platform-oldcore/src/main/java/com/xpn/xwiki/doc/MandatoryDocumentInitializer.java) for this; there is a nice [example](https://github.com/xwiki/xwiki-platform/blob/master/xwiki-platform-core/xwiki-platform-oldcore/src/main/java/com/xpn/xwiki/internal/mandatory/XWikiAllGroupDocumentInitializer.java) in the code base which makes sure the `XWikiAllGroup` is always present.
This interface is meant to ensure that a single page is present in the wiki, but nobody keeps you from checking that other pages are set up properly, too. The only thing you need to have in mind is that the other pages are not saved automatically, but you can do that manually with the `XWiki.saveDocument` method.

To create a user, there is a convenience method `XWiki.createUser(String userName, Map values, XWikiContext context)` in the `XWiki` class. The `values` map contains the values for the attributes to be set on the new user; you can check which attributes are available on the `XWiki.XWikiUsers` page in your wiki.

To create a group, you can borrow code from the example above. Note that to create a new empty group, one adds an object of type `XWiki.XWikiGroups`; to add members to the group one should add one more object of type `XWiki.XWikiGroups` for each user and set the `member` attribute to the full name of the user (i.e. including the 'XWiki.` prefix).

So the class might start with:

```
@Component
@Named("XWiki.MyStandardGroup")
public class MyUserAndGroupsInitializer implements MandatoryDocumentInitializer
{
    private static final String GROUP_CLASS_NAME = "XWikiGroups";
    private static final String MEMBER_ATTR = "member";

    private static final String RIGHTS_CLASS_NAME = "XWikiGlobalRights";
    private static final String GROUPS_ATTR = "groups";
    private static final String USERS_ATTR = "users";
    private static final String RIGHTS_ATTR = "levels"; // ;)
    private static final String ALLOW_ATTR = "allow";
    
    @Inject
    Provider<XWikiContext> contextProvider;

    @Inject
    org.slf4j.Logger logger;
```

The `@Named` contains by convention the name of the page the initializer cares about. That avoids name clashes between initializers on the one hand and allows to overwrite an existing initializer for a page, if wanted. You can choose a differetn name here if you prefer.

The `@Inject`ed compontents are an accessor to the current "context", which allows us to access the data in the current wiki and maintans a database connection in the background. A logger cannot hurt either.

As we need to implement the `MandatoryDocumentInitializer`, we first need to tell the location of one of the pages we care about:

```
    @Override
    public EntityReference getDocumentReference()
    {
        return new LocalDocumentReference(XWiki.SYSTEM_SPACE, "MyStandardGroup");
    }
```

This makes XWiki pass us in the page as a parameter in the next method; we should return `true` here if that page needs to be saved afterwards. As we do e verything by ourselves, we can as well return `false` always.

```
    @Override
    public boolean updateDocument(XWikiDocument document)
    {
        logger.info("try to create users/groups");
        try {
            // here create your users
            // and your groups
        } catch (XWikiException xe) {
            // as we are not allowed to let this through:
            logger.error("failed to create groups", xe);
        }
        return false;
    }
```

That is it, basically. Oh, some possibly useful helpers:

Adding users is relatively easy:

```
    private void createUser(String userFullName)  throws XWikiException
    {
        XWikiContext context = contextProvider.get();
        XWiki xwiki = context.getWiki();

        Map<String,String> values = new HashMap<>();
        values.put("last_name", userFullName);
        values.put("password", "staple battery horses correct");

        int result = xwiki.createUser(userName, values, context);
        if (result > 0) {
            logger.info("user [{}] created", userFullName);
        } else {
            logger.debug("user [{}] aleady exists", userFullName);
        }
    }
```

ok, maybe not *that* simple, but you can start with that one.

It is nearly the same for groups:

```
    // pass in rights as comma separated string, e.g.: "view,comment,edit"
    // members should be the full page name of the user, including the "XWiki." part
    private void createGroup(String group, String rights, String... members)  throws XWikiException
    {
        logger.info("try to create group [{}]", group);
        XWikiDocument groupDoc = checkDocument(XWiki.SYSTEM_SPACE + '.' + group);
        if (groupDoc.isNew()) {
            addUserToGroup(groupDoc, "");
            for (String member : members) {
                addUserToGroup(groupDoc, member);
            }
            XWikiContext context = contextProvider.get();
            XWiki xwiki = context.getWiki();
            xwiki.saveDocument(groupDoc, "created", false, context);
            logger.info("group [{}] created", group);
        }
        setRightsForGroup(groupDoc, rights);
    }
```

and adding users to the group is also easy:

```
    // return true if group needs to be saved afterwards
    private boolean addUserToGroup(XWikiDocument groupDoc, String userName) throws XWikiException
    {
        XWikiContext context = contextProvider.get();
        LocalDocumentReference groupClassReference = new LocalDocumentReference(XWiki.SYSTEM_SPACE, GROUP_CLASS_NAME);

        // first check if the user is already member of the group
        if (groupDoc.getXObject(groupClassReference, MEMBER_ATTR, userName, false) != null) {
            // is already member, no changes necessary
            logger.debug("user [{}] is already member of group [{}]", userName, groupDoc.getFullName());
            return false;
        }
        
        logger.info("add user [{}] to group [{}]", userName, groupDoc.getFullName());
        BaseObject newGroupEntry = groupDoc.newXObject(groupClassReference, context);
        newGroupEntry.setStringValue(MEMBER_ATTR, userName);
        return true;
    }
```

... if it were not for the rights settings that I have moved into a separate helper

```
    // set rights settings for group if it is not set yet; saves the result right away
    private void setRightsForGroup(XWikiDocument groupDoc, String rights) throws XWikiException
    {
        XWikiContext context = contextProvider.get();
        XWiki xwiki = context.getWiki();
        
        LocalDocumentReference rightsClassReference = new LocalDocumentReference(XWiki.SYSTEM_SPACE, RIGHTS_CLASS_NAME);
        String groupName = groupDoc.getFullName();

        // check if the right is already set in the XWikiPreferences.
        // here we need to loop over all values instead   
        XWikiDocument xwikiPrefDocument = xwiki.getDocument(new DocumentReference(context.getWikiId(), XWiki.SYSTEM_SPACE, "XWikiPreferences"), context);
        boolean found = false;
        for (BaseObject rightsSetting : xwikiPrefDocument.getXObjects(rightsClassReference)) {
            if (rights.contentEquals(rightsSetting.getStringValue(RIGHTS_ATTR))
                && rightsSetting.getIntValue(ALLOW_ATTR) == 1) {
                // this is the right setting!
                String groups = rightsSetting.getStringValue(GROUPS_ATTR);
                if (!groups.contains(groupName)) {
                    // our group is missing: add group and save
                    rightsSetting.setStringValue(GROUPS_ATTR, groups + ',' + groupName);
                    xwiki.saveDocument(xwikiPrefDocument, "add rights for group [" + groupName + "]", true, context);
                    logger.info("amended rights for group [{}]", groupName);
                } else {
                    logger.info("rights for group [{}] already set", groupName);
                }
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {
            BaseObject newRightsSetting = xwikiPrefDocument.newXObject(rightsClassReference, context);
            newRightsSetting.setStringValue(RIGHTS_ATTR, rights);
            newRightsSetting.setIntValue(ALLOW_ATTR, 1);
            newRightsSetting.setLargeStringValue(GROUPS_ATTR, groupName);
            if (newRightsSetting.getIntValue(ALLOW_ATTR) != 1) {
                logger.error("adding rights of class [{}] for group [{}] failed!", rightsClassReference, context);
            }
            xwiki.saveDocument(xwikiPrefDocument, "add rights for group [" + groupName + "]", true, context);
            logger.info("added new rights for group [{}]", groupName);
        }
    }
```

I have also used a `checkDocument` helper, which is basically the same as the `updateDocument` in the [XWikiAllGroupInitializer](https://github.com/xwiki/xwiki-platform/blob/master/xwiki-platform-core/xwiki-platform-oldcore/src/main/java/com/xpn/xwiki/internal/mandatory/XWikiAllGroupDocumentInitializer.java), except that the name is input and the tediously newly set up page is the return value.

You might want to read the [Component Guide](https://www.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Documentation/DevGuide/Tutorials/WritingComponents/) to understand how the necessary dependencies get injected. Especially you will need to add the full class name of the initializer to the `src/main/resources/META-INF/components.txt` for the initializer to get activated.

Backup your database before you try this out. Except a few tries before everything is properly set up, and nothing gets saved unnecessarily on each wiki restart.
Also fiddle with the `WEB-INF/classes/logback.xml` to set the level to `INFO` for your package, if you want to see the log messages.

---

### Some random other advice

Instead of managing your users programatically you might consider storing then in a LDAP Server and use this for authentication with the [LDAP Authenticator](https://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/LDAP/Authenticator/). (You still need to create the groups and manage their rights, however)

While developing I found it very useful to have the [Scripting Reference Documentation](https://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/Scripting%20Documentation%20Application) extension installed in my development wiki. It is no a replacement for any documentation, but being able to brwose the API Javadoc interactively somehow helps me a lot.

The [Admin Tools](https://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/Admin%20Tools%20Application) extension has a page that shows you all rights granted in the current wiki where this extension is installed. (Go to `.../xwiki/bin/view/Admin/` and click "Show Rights".)

Comment: Awesome answer. I really appreciate the time you took to compose such a detailed answer to help me. I'm still reading it, probably will go through it multiple times to fully understand it. However, regarding a possible typo: *"You now can grant a right to user or group **to** every page.."* should be *"You now can grant a right to user or group **for** every page.."* ? English isn't my native language, so maybe what you wrote is grammatically correct. But my confusion is, rights can be granted to user or group, not to a page, but for a page (and possibly a page with its children), right?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying *"That the attribute levels here actually stores the rights is maybe confusing - again this is another historical decision. (The software is developed since 15 years or so and the developers are commited to keep backwards compatibility). **Whatever the attribute is named, these are rights, and not the levels the documentation talks about.**"*, I hope somebody improves the official docs.

Comment: I have updated my answer; there is still some sample code to come up tomorrow. Thanks for pointing out the grammatical error; of course one does not grant a right *to* a page but *for* a page. No native speaker here either.  I will see if I can improve the official docs, but I think the best I can do is add the examples.

Comment: Thanks for the great additions to the already awesome answer. Just one question: why did you suggest to implement `MandatoryDocumentInitializer` and create the users and groups inside `updateDocument`? I am extending `XWikiAuthServiceImpl` and create the users and groups in `checkAuth`. Basically, my users will be authenticated using Google IAP, so by the time `checkAuth` is invoked, the request contains the essential informations (such as email-ids, etc) as the headers. So I used that information to create users (and groups) if not already created before.

Comment: If I use `updateDocument`, I'd not know the users to be created? I saw some of the authentication extensions, such as [xwiki-authenticator-headers](https://github.com/xwiki-contrib/xwiki-authenticator-headers/blob/master/src/main/java/com/xwiki/authentication/headers/XWikiHeadersAuthenticator.java) which `extends XWikiAuthServiceImpl` . I just changed it to work with Google IAP. Also, I didn't use the Component architecture (because I didn't know how it works, I'm not a Java guy), but seeing the xwiki docs on it, it seems pretty straightforward, but dont know what is the right approach here.

Comment: Apart from that, is there a way to have more than one approaches to login? Like `Login with Google IAP` (a button which takes you to google to authenticate) and other a form-based, the wiki default one, which ask username and password? Currently, my wiki url directly goes to google to authenticate (it not already authenticated) without showing any login screen, or "Login with Google" button, at all. I'm wondering how to show the login screen and customize it. (I can live without it though, as I think I can live without `superadmin` login, if few automatically regular users are `admin`)

Comment: I did not know about your requirements, so the `MandatoryDocumentInitializer` seemed the simplest way to do it. However if you want to create the user profile pages on the fly when they login, then that will not work for users, but just for the groups. The `XWikiHeadersAuthenticator` actually does something like creating/updating users on the fly in the `synchronizeUser`. All you need to change is the `addUserToXWikiGroup` helper which throws an exception of the group does not exist; instead create the group as in the example above.

Comment: You will need to overwrite the `login.vm` template to add buttons to access different login approaches. One example for this is in the "social login" extension at https://github.com/xwiki-contrib/xwiki-social-login/blob/master/xwiki-social-login-ui/src/main/webapp/templates/login.vm  Instead of directly editing it in the `skins/flamingo/login.vm` on the file system you can also attach a `login.vm` to the `XWiki.DefaultSkin` page to override the login view, or use the wiki administration, as explained in the https://extensions.xwiki.org/xwiki/bin/view/Extension/Skin%20Application.

Comment: Oh, and I forgot: like in the `XWikiHeadersAuthenticator`, if you extend `XWikiAuthServiceImpl` and call `super.checkAuth(username, password, rememberme, context)` in case your custom authentication fails, you should get the usual password-based login, which tests against the user's password stored in the database.

Comment: Awesome. I think from here I can work and implement the features I need. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I tried few things, and keep reading this post, each time I understand new thing. Now I'm doing this: for each user `/view/XWiki/Nawaz`, I'm also creating a Home page at `/view/Users/Nawaz`, bascially `Users.Nawaz.WebHome`, with `edit` rights only to this user, so I'm creating `Users.Nawaz.WebPreferences` where I add an object of type `XWiki.XWikiGlobalRights` with the `edit` right to this user only. It seems to work, however `WebPreferences` page is visible at `/view/Users/Nawaz/WebPreferences`. Is this page supposed to be _visible_? I thought it is like `WebHome` and is invisible.

Comment: I'm using `defaultDocumentReferenceResolver.resolve("Users.Nawaz.WebHome");` and `defaultDocumentReferenceResolver.resolve("Users.Nawaz.WebPreferences");` to create the `DocumentReference` objects from which `XWikiDocument` objects are created and then set the rights, and `saveDocument()`. I dont create any `Users` _space_ anywhere. I assume it is being created automatically (by the resolver, I guess?).

Comment: I read your answer again. Now I understand all the necessary concepts and I made my code work. Please ignore my previous two comments. :-)